# Anyone know a video editing prog that works with Intel + OS 12.4?

Tags: macos, monterey, imovie, final-cut-pro, software-recommendation

I would love iMovie but I cannot find a version that works with my system.
2016 MacBookPro running OS 12.4, that's with the Intel chip.

The latest version of iMovie needs the M1 chip and OS 13x.  I can't find any versions that work with Monterey AND the Intel chip.

I just want to assemble edit some dumb cat videos but I can't find a single video program that will work.  There doesn't even seem to be a version of Premiere or Final Cut that will work with my system.

This is all so crazy since in the 90s I was a video editor and used Premiere v3.

Comment: If you access the App Store from the MBP running 12.4, do you get the M1 version of iMovie or an older one running on Intel?

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Premiere](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html#macos) and [DaVinci Resolve](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/davinci-resolve/id571213070?mt=12) both support macOS 12.4, as do previous versions of Final Cut Pro/iMovie, both of which are still accessible via the App Store. If you want to use the latest version of Final Cut Pro/iMovie, I'd suggest using [OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html#macbook-pro) to get your MacBook Pro onto macOS 14.